# Ghostscript version for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript, postscript

I installed Ghostscript.NET(1.2.1) for VS2017 from nuget and its generate PS files with heading:

```
%%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 905
```

It is possible update it to 9.25?

Comment: I think you should have two native Ghostscript dll on your app (gsdll32.dll / gsdll64.dll) after installing that package: try to update both to desired release

Comment: yes, just replaced gsd32.dll and gsdll64 in the bin folder of my project, and it helped. thanks!